# What is the difference between eth_sign and personal_sign?

Tags: solidity, metamask, sendsignedtransaction

I am digging into the difference between `eth_sign` and `personal_sign`.

What I found is that `personal_sign` is way more secure than `eth_sign`.

**why?**

`eth_sign` encrypts message with the user's private key and return the raw data.
malicious dapp could take the data and send a transaction.

**In contrast to eth_sign,**

`personal_sign` avoid this problem since it add "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" as prefix data to the user's data.

**However, I have no idea of how the prefix** `"\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n"` **can be against malicious action.**

Please explain this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metmask's `eth_sign` still uses an outdated version of the modern JSON-RPC `eth_sign` discussed on [Ethereum.org](https://Ethereum.org). This means that this method can be used to sign any hash which can then create a transaction on your behalf once sent to the blockchain. You can read about why it's not recommended [here](https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/14764161421467-What-is-eth-sign-and-why-is-it-a-risk-).

[EIP 191](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-191) introduced the `"\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n"` prefix to signed messages. See this quote from the `eth_sign` [section](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_sign) on Ethereum.org's list of JSON-RPC methods:

> By adding a prefix to the message makes the calculated signature recognizable as an Ethereum specific signature. This prevents misuse where a malicious dapp can sign arbitrary data (e.g. transaction) and use the signature to impersonate the victim.

See [EIP 712](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712) for a standardized way to sign structured data, this is compatible with [EIP 191](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-191) and is a safer method of signing transactions since the data is human readable and the intent of the transaction is easily verifiable.

You can read about Metamask's current version of this method, `eth_signTypedData_v4` [here](https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/how-to/sign-data/#use-eth_signtypeddata_v4).

Answer (score 1):

Malicious attacker can request the user the sign a transfer transaction that once signed, can be immediately broadcasted to the network.

updated: it seems now both eth_sign and personal_sign prepend "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" for most signers.

to sign binary data to be processed on chain, in metamask, use:
https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/how-to/sign-data/#use-eth_signtypeddata_v4

Comment: All nodes on all EVM chains prepend eth_sign?